# How to apply <span> tag to My Cart top link in magento?

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.7

I have changed texts My cart to My Shopping Bag in top links through below code.

```
public function addCartLink()
{
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
                : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
            if ($count == 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag (%s)', $count);
            } elseif ($count > 0) {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag (%s)', $count);
            } else {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag');
            }

            $parentBlock->removeLinkByUrl($this->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Now, I want to apply  tag to shopping cart quantity. 
So, It should look like My Shopping Bag 0. 0 (quantity) should be in red color. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` can be added directly.

```
public function addCartLink()
{
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
                : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
            if ($count == 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag <span>(%s)</span>', $count);
            } elseif ($count > 0) {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag <span>(%s)</span>', $count);
            } else {
                $text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag');
            }

            $parentBlock->removeLinkByUrl($this->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: it can't be applied directly because there is html escaping method when link is rendered

Answer (score 0):

your code is right but in else part its want tricky way.
you can show like this
$text = $this->__('My Shopping Bag (0)');
may its help you

Thanks
Anand